# data passing by one to one field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models `Employee` and `myCustomeUser` in my **Django** project.

My `models.py`:

```
class myCustomeUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(default="abcdef", max_length=150, unique="True")
    password = models.CharField(default="12345", max_length=150)
    is_Employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Inspector = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_IndustryOwner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_Admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(myCustomeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True, related_name='releted_user')
    extraField = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Now I am trying to entry an Employee's data with `views.py` like this:

```
Employee_obj = Employee.objects.create(releted_user.username=this_username, releted_user.password=this_password, releted_user.is_Employee=True)
Employee_obj.save()
```

But It shows error like this:

```
Employee_obj = Employee.objects.create(releted_user.username=this_username, releted_user.password=this_password, releted_user.is_Employee=True)
                                           ^
SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
```

How can I solve this problem? Mainly I need to save any employee's data by `Employee.objects.create()`

Comment: You can not work with `create(foo.bar=....)` that is just illegal Python syntax.

Comment: then how can I create an object for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not work with `.create(foo.bar=…)` that is just illegal Python syntax. If you need to create an object that is referenced throug a `OneToOneField`, you first create that object, like:

```
u = myCustomeUser.objects.create(
    username=this_username,
    password=this_password,
    is_Employee=True
)

Employee_obj = Employee.objects.create(user=u)
```

Please do *not* store raw passwords. Django normally *hashes* passwords. See the [*how does Django stores passwords* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords).

Comment: thanks a lot, now it is working perfectly!